# How to send custom object and headers using RestTemplate of Spring

Tags: spring, resttemplate, spring-rest

I want to send a custom object and custom headers as a POST request to an URL using RestTemplate. The following is the code i'm using;

```
    MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    headers.add("Authorization: key=", SERVER_KEY);
    headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

    CustomDataModel customDataModel = new CustomDataModel();
    customDataModel.setTitle(message);
    customDataModel.setBody(rowId);

    CustomNotificationModel customNotificationModel = new CustomNotificationModel();
    customNotificationModel.setRegistration_ids(list);
    customNotificationModel.setPriority("high");
    customNotificationModel.setData(customDataModel);

    HttpEntity<CustomNotificationModel> entity = new HttpEntity<CustomNotificationModel>(customNotificationModel, headers);

    restTemplate.postForLocation(REST_SERVICE_URI, entity);
```

But it is giving me the following error;

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Internal Server Error
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:94)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:641)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:597)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:557)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:475)
at com.humworld.sync.restclient.RestClient.notifyUser(RestClient.java:68)
at com.humworld.sync.controller.SyncRestController.saveUserDetails(SyncRestController.java:94)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:832)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Please advice what changes do i need to make.

Comment: Please provide more information about the controller and the mvc configuration. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i made a mistake in the Authorization header, it has to be like this;

```
headers.add("Authorization", "key=" + SERVER_KEY);
```

The code is working fine, once again sorry.